# Trying to make a Server application with socket and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-sockets

I am trying to make this Socket & tkinter server app the point in Short form is this is a tk window that basically makes a socket server with some `Buttons` and some `Entrys`. And the thing is the server maker is not working. this is what mean the script i made when i fill up the Entrys and when i press on the "Create Server" button, i am supposed to get a `print("Server Made!")` but what i get instead is
`Python is not responding` wow aren't those THE BEST WORDS? i am just kidding.

this is my code/script:

```
from tkinter import *
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import time
import socket








def Client(ip,port,Cname):
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect((str(ip), int(port)))
        msg = client.recv(4096)
        print(msg.decode("utf-8"))




#Server Dashboard
def __main__SD():
    tk = Tk()
    tk.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
    
    tk.title('SECL-Dashboard')
    
    x = int(GetSystemMetrics(0))
    y = int(GetSystemMetrics(1))
    
    
    Top_Frame = Frame(width=x,height=50,bg='orange')
    Top_Frame.place(x=0,y=0)
    
    X_Button = Button(tk,width=5,height=1,text='X',bg='red',fg='white',command=tk.destroy)
    X_Button.place(x=1500,y=2)
    
    X_Button.config(font =("Bold", 16))
    
    
    tk.mainloop()
    
    print("Exiting")
    


    
    


# Config-CLIENT
def CONFIG2():
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    
    root.title("SECL-Client")
    root.geometry('400x500')
    x = Frame(height = 60,width = 600,bg='green')
    x.pack()
    
    TITLE = Label(root,text = "SECL",bg='green',fg='white')
    TITLE.place(x=140,y=4)
    TITLE.config(font =("Bold", 30))
    
    TP = Label(root,text='Client',bg='green',fg='white')
    TP.place(x=252,y=30)
    TP.config(font=("Bold",15))
    
    #Create Button
    
    JoinB = Button(root,width=12,height=2,text='Join Server',bg='#00FF00',command=lambda:[root.destroy(),__main__SD()]) #Server Join
    JoinB.place(x=90,y=440)
    
    
    #Cancle Button
    CancelB = Button(root,width=12,height=2,text='Cancel',bg='#D3D3D3',command=root.destroy)
    CancelB.place(x=200,y=440)
    
    CB = Button(root,width=5,height=2,text='<',bg='#FFFFFF',command=lambda:[root.destroy(),CONFIG1()])
    CB.place(x=350,y=455)
    CB.config(font=("Bold",10))
    
    
    #Join
    port_I = Label(root,text='Port:')
    port_I.place(x=100,y=145)
    port_I.config(font =("Bold", 15))
    
    
    IP_I = Label(root,text='IP:')
    IP_I.place(x=100,y=200)
    IP_I.config(font =("Bold", 15))
    
    
    CN_I = Label(root,text='Client name:')
    CN_I.place(x=30,y=245)
    CN_I.config(font =("Bold", 15))
    
    
    
    ip = Entry(root,fg='black')
    ip.place(width=155,height=20)
    ip.place(x=150,y=200)    
    
    
    port = Entry(root,fg='black')
    port.place(width=155,height=20)
    port.place(x=150,y=150)
    
    
    cn = Entry(root,fg='black')
    cn.place(width=155,height=20)
    cn.place(x=150,y=245)
    root.mainloop()



#Config-SERVER
def CONFIG1():
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    
    root.title("SECL-Config")
    root.geometry('400x500')
    x = Frame(height = 60,width = 600,bg='blue')
    x.pack()
    
    TITLE = Label(root,text = "SECL",bg='blue',fg='white')
    TITLE.place(x=140,y=4)
    TITLE.config(font =("Bold", 30))
    
    TP = Label(root,text='Server',bg='blue',fg='white')
    TP.place(x=252,y=30)
    TP.config(font=("Bold",15))
    
    
    
    #Cancle Button
    CancleB = Button(root,width=12,height=2,text='Cancel',bg='#D3D3D3',command=root.destroy)
    CancleB.place(x=200,y=440)
    
    
    #Client Button
    
    CB = Button(root,width=5,height=2,text='>',bg='#FFFFFF',command=lambda:[root.destroy(),CONFIG2()])
    CB.place(x=350,y=455)
    CB.config(font=("Bold",10))
    
    
    # INFO
    port_I = Label(root,text='Port:')
    port_I.place(x=80,y=145)
    port_I.config(font =("Bold", 15))
    
    
    
    Name_I = Label(root,text='Server Name:')
    Name_I.place(x=10,y=200)
    Name_I.config(font =("Bold", 15))
    
    
    MClient_I = Label(root,text="Max Client:")
    MClient_I.place(x=20,y=245)
    MClient_I.config(font =("Bold", 15))
    
    
    
    
    
    port = Entry(root,fg='black')
    port.place(width=155,height=20)
    port.place(x=150,y=150)
    
    
    name = Entry(root,fg='black')
    name.place(width=155,height=20)
    name.place(x=150,y=200)
    
    
    mclient = Entry(root,fg='black')
    mclient.place(width=155,height=20)
    mclient.place(x=150,y=245)
    
    
    def ALL_POINT():
        serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        serv.bind((str(ip), int(port.get())))
        serv.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        serv.listen(int(mclient.get()))
    
        conn, addr = serv.accept()
            #data = conn.recv(int(max_people))
        conn.send(bytes(f"Welcome to {name.get()}!",'utf-8'))
        print("Server: Running")
        

    #Create Button
    #CreateB = Button(root,width=12,height=2,text='Create Server',bg='#00FF00',command=lambda:[root.destroy(),ALL_POINT()])
    CreateB = Button(root,width=12,height=2,text='Create Server',bg='#00FF00',command=ALL_POINT)
    CreateB.place(x=90,y=440)
    
    
    
    
    root.mainloop()
    


CONFIG1()
```

No error's Nothing but i just get that `Python is not responding`
Is there a way i can fix or better remove this bug from my script?
Btw i am running windows 7.

Comment: It is because `serv.accept()` is a blocking function.  You should run `ALL_POINT()` in a child thread instead.

Comment: Could you please provide some code :)

Answer (score 3):

As `serv.accept()` is a blocking function, it will block tkinter mainloop from handling events.

You need to run `ALL_POINT()` in a child thread:

```py
import threading
...

def CONFIG1():
    ...

    server_running = False

    # sample client handler
    def handle_client(conn, addr):
        conn.send(bytes(f"Welcome to {name.get()}!",'utf-8'))
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(512).decode().strip()
            print(data)
            if data == 'quit':
                break
        conn.close()

    def ALL_POINT():
        nonlocal server_running

        serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        print(ip, port.get())
        serv.bind((str(ip), int(port.get())))
        serv.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        serv.listen(int(mclient.get()))
    
        print("Server: Running")
        server_running = True
        while server_running:
            print('waiting connection ...')
            conn, addr = serv.accept()
            print('client connected', addr)
            # run client handler in thread so that server can serve new connection
            threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr), daemon=True).start()

    def start_server():
        # make sure only one server task is active
        if not server_running:
            threading.Thread(target=ALL_POINT, daemon=True).start()

    CreateB = Button(root, width=12, height=2, text='Create Server',
                     bg='#00FF00', command=start_server)
```

Comment: I still do get ```Python is not responding``` but this is what happens when i fill out the entrys and i press on the button it shows my ip in the output bar and the port i am using.
after that i get ```Python is not responding```

Comment: also i can not connect to the server through another computer!

Comment: Update the question with the changed you made.

Comment: Update the posted code with the changes you made based on my solution.